# Accessing External Files Into Our Web Application

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web, struts-1

This question might be asked many times, but I did not find a direct answer.

Actually I am using WebSphere for running my Java web application, I wanted to save/store  my uploaded files/resources to folder outside server directory, say `D:/resources/` but my concern is, is it possible that we do this? As this might be sort of security breach.

If it is possible then how to do it in Java web applications.

Comment: It is possible and the solution is easy to be found. Please do some own research or at least show(!) that you have tried. A question that "might be asked many times" will almost always will be asked many times and thous will have a ready to use solution.

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer thanx for quick reply, i have searched in google, had some experiment, but was getting error, i am trying to find its ans, thanks.

Comment: Okay, WHAT did you find, WHAT did you try and WHAT errors are you getting. (Also Writing "ans" instead of "answer" and similar abbreviations reduce the readability of your questions and thus will reduce the interest other people in helping you. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask )

Comment: Hi @AngeloNeuschitzer please have a look on my other question which is continuation of this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19178394/how-to-display-image-which-is-outside-server-directory-in-strtus

Answer (score 0):

Below is code for uploading files in struts 1.x

```
public class MyModel extends ActionForm {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private FormFile file = null;

    public void setFile(FormFile file) {
        this.file = file;
    }

    public FormFile getFile() {
        return this.file;
    }

}



public class FileUploadAction extends DispatchAction{

MyModel m = (MyModel) form;
FormFile myFile = m.getFile();

String contentType = myFile.getContentType();
String fileName = myFile.getFileName();

int fileSize = myFile.getFileSize();
byte[] fileData = myFile.getFileData();

String recieveMaterialFileName = myFile.getFileName();
File newFile = new File("D:/resources/images", recieveMaterialFileName);

if(!newFile.exists()){
      FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
            fos.write(myFile.getFileData());
            fos.flush();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println("Error " + e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Error " + e);
        }finally{
            fos.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello. First, you are abusing the "answer" section. That code should go to the "question" (there is a edit thing there). Second: the Path "D:/..." will not exist in unix based systems. What path are you using there? And what Exeception do you get? Third: use `e.printStackTrace()` instead of `"Error " + e"` it will be much more useful.

Comment: Thanks @AngeloNeuschitzer your suggestions are valuable for me and I will remember them all. While I am in windows I am using the above path i.e D:/resources/images/ but when I am running my application in unix based system I am using /resources/images/

Comment: Thats great. Please edit the information from your two answers into your question so it is in one place not in three. Then delete your answers (as questions with no answers usually get more attention). Also please try the suggestions I gave you and include the results of those in the question as well.