# How to display an image which is outside of the server directory in Struts

Tags: java, ajax, image, jsp, struts

This question is continuation to my previous question [Accessing External Files Into Our Web Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19089175/accessing-external-files-into-our-web-application), actually I am uploading file using Struts tag `<html:file property="file" />`

But now I wanted to show the uploaded images from that location but I am getting `src` location as `http://localhost:9443/D:/resources/images/img1.jpg` which is not a valid path for that image.

**How to access that image which is outside my server directory.**

This is how I am sending Ajax response with **Absolute path** of images

```
public ActionForward getAjaxUploadedFiles(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception
    {
        
        String imagePath = "D:/resources/images/";
        ArrayList<String> path = new ArrayList<String>();
        
        File imageFile = new File(imagePath);
        File imageFiles[] = imageFile.listFiles();
        
        for (int i = 0; i < imageFiles.length; i++) {
            path.add(imageFiles[i].getAbsolutePath());
        }
        
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        response.setContentType("text/xml");
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        
        StringBuffer strXMl = new StringBuffer();
        strXMl.append("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>");
        strXMl.append("<start>"); 
        
        
        for (String imagePth : path) {
            strXMl.append("<imagePath>");
            strXMl.append(imagePth);
            strXMl.append("</imagePath>");
        }
        
        strXMl.append("</start>");
        
        if(strXMl != null){ 
            String Xml = strXMl.toString();
            out.write(Xml);
            System.err.println("XMl Reponse is: " + Xml);
        }
        else {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
        }
        out.flush();
        
        return mapping.findForward(null);
    }
```

This is how I am rendering images at JSP

```
 $(response).find("imagePath").each(function() {
            row = tblReportList.insertRow(0);
            row.className="TableBordergray";
            row.style.width="100%";
            
            var imagePath = $(this).text();
                    
            cell = row.insertCell(0);
            cell.innerHTML="<img src='" + imagePath + "' alt='" + imagePath + "' height='42' width='42'>";
        });
```

but at `<img>` tag I am getting image path as `http://localhost:9443/D:/resources/images/img1.jpg`

Comment: What is a src location?

Comment: thanks for quick reply src location is D:/resources/images/ i.e. outside server directory.

Comment: Post the code with comment where you are getting this.

Comment: sorry I am getting this error while posting: Users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. You can answer in 7 hours. Until then please use comments, or edit your question instead.

Comment: You should not answer your question EXCEPT when you have an ANSWER to your QUESTION. If you want to add details use the EDIT feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't render images in such way. Web server treated your image path as relative and add qualifying url location on the server. You should create an action to serve images, for example

```
<action path="/image" ... scope="request" validate="false"/>
```

Then render HTML like

```
cell.innerHTML="<img src='" + '/image?path=' + imagePath + "' alt='" + imagePath + "' height='42' width='42'>";
```

Now, create the action that write the binary image data to the response output stream. Take a parameter `path` in the action that let you find a file for binary output. After the flushing output return `null` so struts should not forward the action further. You could also add headers to turn off a `Cache-Control` to make sure the images are retrieved from the server.

Answer (score 2):

Hi Below is the answer to my question, I have created `ImageServlet` for displaying image, steps to perform:

**1. you need to add mapping in web.xml file:**

```
    <servlet-name>ImageServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ImageServlet/*</url-pattern>
```

**2. create** `ImageServlet`:

```
public class ImageServlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException
    {

        //Setting image path
        ImageLocationService locationService = new ImageLocationService();

        try {
            String imageCategory = request.getParameter("imageCategory");
            if (imageCategory != null) {
                this.imagePath = locationService.getImageLocation(imageCategory);
            }else{
                this.imagePath = ConfigConstants.imageLocation;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Get requested image by path info.
        String requestedImage = request.getPathInfo();

        // Check if file name is actually supplied to the request URI.
        if (requestedImage == null) {
            // Do your thing if the image is not supplied to the request URI.
            // Throw an exception, or send 404, or show default/warning image, or just ignore it.
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND); // 404.
            return;
        }

        // Decode the file name (might contain spaces and on) and prepare file object.
        File image = new File(imagePath, URLDecoder.decode(requestedImage, "UTF-8"));

        // Check if file actually exists in filesystem.
        if (!image.exists()) {
            // Do your thing if the file appears to be non-existing.
            // Throw an exception, or send 404, or show default/warning image, or just ignore it.
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND); // 404.
            return;
        }

        // Get content type by filename.
        String contentType = getServletContext().getMimeType(image.getName());

        // Check if file is actually an image (avoid download of other files by hackers!).
        // For all content types, see: http://www.w3schools.com/media/media_mimeref.asp
        if (contentType == null || !contentType.startsWith("image")) {
            // Do your thing if the file appears not being a real image.
            // Throw an exception, or send 404, or show default/warning image, or just ignore it.
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND); // 404.
            return;
        }

        // Init servlet response.
        response.reset();
        response.setBufferSize(DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);
        response.setContentType(contentType);
        response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(image.length()));
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + image.getName() + "\"");

        // Prepare streams.
        BufferedInputStream input = null;
        BufferedOutputStream output = null;

        try {
            // Open streams.
            input = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(image), DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);
            output = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream(), DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);

            // Write file contents to response.
            byte[] buffer = new byte[DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE];
            int length;
            while ((length = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                output.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
        } finally {
            // Gently close streams.
            close(output);
            close(input);
        }
    }

    private static void close(Closeable resource) {
        if (resource != null) {
            try {
                resource.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // Do your thing with the exception. Print it, log it or mail it.
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**3. At jsp side you need to add the mapping in step 1 in your** `img` **tag i.e. input type='image':**

```
<input  type="image" alt='No image found' src='../ImageServlet/append image name that you want to display' />
```

You can even create `Action` class and use `execute` method for doing the same.