# Not able to display higher resolution image in browser

Tags: css, image, internet-explorer-8, browser

I am not able to display images on browser(in img tag) which are about 2700 x 1800 or more in dimension, is there a way to display such large images on browser.

I am getting a broken image icon as below:

[image: broken image]

Comment: Do other browsers display the image correctly?

Comment: Are you sure the format is one the browser supports (Like PNG or JPG)? And you've verified that the file path is correct?

Comment: Yup, it is JPG format and path is also correct.

Comment: @Oswald No, I tried on chrome, IE and firefox, these browsers does not display that image.

Comment: What happens when you enter the image URL into the address bar directly?

Comment: How this one is working :  http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/79/Clitterhouse_Recreation_Ground.JPG  Click on Zoom ....This is 3648 X 2736

Comment: Your browser is not getting ur image.

Comment: @Oswald Error 404: SRVE0295E: Error reported: 404

Comment: **404** Means "not found" suggesting that the path is incorrect. Check the URL again. If you're 100% sure it's correct, try googling the other part of the error (SRVE0295E), some answers say things like "Make sure that the content in not in draft stage!"

Answer (score 0):

The URL in the `src`-attribute of the `<img>` tag does not point to the image on your server. Use the correct URL in the `src`-attribute of the `<img>` tag.

Comment: @oswals I have checked for the url through tool of chrome "inspect element" it is correct but it is not getting displayed in browser. I am using ImageServlet http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19178394/how-to-display-image-which-is-outside-server-directory-in-strtus/19354621 to display image.

Comment: If the URL were correct, you wouldn't have gotten a `404` when you entered the image URL into the address bar directly.

Comment: also I got this message on firefox "The image "https://test.com/ImageServlet/LargeImage.png" cannot be displayed because it contains errors" in chrome it get downloaded but did not displays on screen, when I change that image to lower some lower resolution it gets displayed.

Comment: outside browser, image is also opening when I am trying to open.

Comment: @user2704032 Is it possible the server is serving large files with a different http header or something like that? In any case, this sounds like a server issue. Try opening the local image in the browser directly (just drag and drop) and I'll bet it displays just fine ;)

Comment: @xec thanks, atleast this gives me approach I should follow to check the issue. :)

Answer (score 0):

If the URL in the src-attribute is correct and the image is available in the specified path, there will be no issue in displaying the image, no matter whatever resolution and browser it is. You may face issues in IOS while displaying high resolution images.