# Is there a way to dynamically embed PDF Files in a JSP pulled from the file system?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, pdf, embed

I understand that it is possible to embed a PDF that is located on the server (ex: `<object data="pdf/Test.pdf"/>` however is it possible to somehow embed a PDF that's located within the filesystem?

ex: `<iframe src="\\filesystem\some\where\in\here\pdf.pdf"></iframe>`

If not are there any tricks to doing so?

Comment: One "trick" I've used in the past is to have a servlet that has limited access to the file system. The servlet retrieves the requests data from the filesystem and sends it across the HttpServletResponse. It works the same as embedding a file that lives on the webserver, be lets you conceal the filesystem pathing by having a single servlet

Comment: How would having a dedicated servlet accessing the filesystem be any different than having the primary servlet do it?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19178394/how-to-display-image-which-is-outside-server-directory-in-strtus/19354621#19354621), instead of sending image data you can send `pdf` data to display. It is implemented using servlet.

**Example:**

> `<iframe src="../loadPdf/pdfFileName.pdf" width="800px" height="600px" >`

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SendPdfData</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.YourServletClass</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SendPdfData</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/loadPdf/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Take reference from [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19178394/how-to-display-image-which-is-outside-server-directory-in-strtus/19354621#19354621) to know how to send file data from `YourServletClass` servlet.

Comment: Could you explain in further detail what you are doing here?

<input  type="image" alt='No image found' src='../ImageServlet/append image name that you want to display' />

Comment: `/ImageServlet/` is URL pattern given as src of img input type, wherever there is URL pattern like `/ImageServlet` it will call configured Servlet in your `web.xml` file, the Servlet will send the data (in your case pdf) and load into specified tag (if tag is applicable to hold that data).

Comment: `/ImageServlet/` **+** give pdf file name

Comment: Could you give me an example of what I would need to put into my web.xml for this functionality to occur

Comment: as I explained in other answer in 1st step that you have to add mapping for URL-pattern and servlet in your web.xml file. you can use that example here, use can change names according to your requirement.

Comment: Yeah I understand how to map a servlet in Web XML.  I'm not seeing how this would direct any of the output from my servlet to the IFrame however.

I am still either having the document load into another window, or load in the window directly